# What's wrong with my Python installation?

Tags: python, installation

I downloaded and installed Python 3.1.2 on Windows 7 x64. But it seems that it's not working as expected.

What's wrong here?

Comment: This question featured an image not on the official Stack Overflow CDN, and predictably it is no longer available. I have removed it, which means the question is now off-topic, since it lacks a [mcve]. I will try to close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print "Today's stock price: %f" % 50.4625
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Today's stock price: %f" % 50.4625
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("Today's stock price: %f" % 50.4625)
Today's stock price: 50.462500
```

Python 3.X changed how print works, and now requires parentheses around the arguments.

Comment: You saved my life. I have to wait 10 minutes to accept this answer :)

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to edit my post, but you can check here: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html for other changes.

Comment: new format style: 
print("Today's stock price: {0}".format(50.4625))

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.X is not backward-compatible with Python 2.X.  Make sure you are reading a 3.X tutorial, or remove 3.X and install 2.X.

Here's some reading about why there are differences and to decide which to use: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, print is now function and needs `()`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above python 3.x now requires all statements such as those to be function calls, Python 3.x is supposed to bring back the functional aspect of C to python although code that works in 3.x will most likely work in 2.x but not necessarily the other way around.